# add a lot of editable div

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a lot of editable div text. I can edit but only first div.

```
$(function() {
        $(".add-new").click(function() {
            $('.image').append("<div id='new-text'></div>")
        });
        $('#writable').keydown(function() {
            var writable_value = $('#writable').val();
            $('#new-text').html(writable_value)
        });
    }
)
```

my form

```
<form>
        <input type="text" id="writable">
        <buton type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-new">add new text</buton>
</form>
```

and if I click on the selected div I can edit it

Comment: since you are using `id` for new-text you can edit only one div, if it needs to be dynamic then each new-text div should have different ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/nbk6rjtp/)**

Here is what you can do:

Add dynamic `id` each time and then change values of all `editable` div whose `id` starts with some common value:

```
$(function() {
        var count=0;//global variable to add unique id div
        $(".add-new").click(function() {
            $('.image').append("<div id='new-text_"+count+"' contenteditable>Edit me</div>")
            //divs will be new-text_1,new-text_2 etc.,
            count++;
        });
        $('#writable').keydown(function() {
            var writable_value = $('#writable').val();
            $("div[id^=new-text]").text(writable_value);
            //The above selector changes values of all div whose id starts with new-text
        });
    }
)
```

---

**UPDATE**

Got your point of adding more `div` and editing and replacing texts. you just need to change below line

```
$("div[id^=new-text]").text(writable_value);
```

to

```
$("div[id^=new-text]:last").text(writable_value);
//Always target the last added textbox
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/nbk6rjtp/2/)**

Comment: instead of making count fully global, you can move it to within your closure and it will still work, that way it won't mess up any plugins that use a count var (it is a very common var name!): https://jsfiddle.net/peteng/nbk6rjtp/1/

Comment: Thank you this is what I need but It has one error If I add many div and edit input all div is changed

Comment: At initial I thought of that @Pete but then I thought it won't make much difference.. After seeing you comment I feel yea it does make some difference... Thank you though...

Comment: the result of the input text will be visible only as something selected or add a new div

Comment: So the result of input text should be changed and reflected only in first div?

Comment: I think so but try add a few div and change also font size or font family from form UPDATED LINK http://finance.usermd.net/customizer/index.html

Comment: I do not want create new topic so I ask here I add '$("div[id^=new-text]:last").draggable();' 
and I would like to change param last on active ie. current selected but it is not work

Comment: See you have some more fields now like select and all so that will fall as different question.. It's against the rule of SO to add question into question once answered.. I don't mind answering.. But again it's against rules of SO..